# Mod Rewrite on php pages with queries

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have XAMPP installed on laptop with Mod Rewrite activated and running. I have a page on my website as following:

```
http://localhost/TripMan/staff/viewstudent.php?id=2
```

I would like to make it so that when people visit the URL above it is displayed as:

```
http://localhost/TripMan/staff/studentinfo/2
```

How would I write a rewrite rule to do this? I have never used this feature before.

Thanks

Comment: try to search a little on stack overflow, I'm quite sure you'll find answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `.htaccess` file like so:

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Set student rewrite
RewriteRule ^TripMan/staff/studentinfo/([0-9]*)/?$ TripMan/staff/viewstudent.php?id=$2 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Should that be `RewriteRule ^(/TripMan/staff/studentinfo/)([0-9]*)$ TripMan/staff/viewstudent.php?id=$2 [NC,QSA]` ?

Comment: @symcbean Both should work, was just an example really :-) Will amend